# Modifiable bullet list in Django

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, django-views

I currently have a list generated in `views.py` that is displayed by bullet points on the wanted page by the template:

`views.py`:

```
bullet_list = ['Apple starts with A','Banana starts with B','Carrot starts with C']
context = {'bullet_list': bullet_list}
return render(request, 'example.html', context)
```

`example.html`:

```
{% if bullet_list %}
    <ul style="width: 800px;">
    {% for bullet in bullet_list %}
        <li style="list-style-type: circle;">{{bullet}}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endif %}
```

I would like it so the user can add/remove/adjust the bullet points and save the adjusted bullet points. Ideally, when they go back on the page, their new changes are there instead.

I was able to get it to delete a bullet (shown below), but I was unsure of how to get it to save that it was deleted and how to get input entered to be another bullet:

`example.html`:

```
<li onclick="this.parentNode.removeChild(this);  onmouseover="this.setAttribute('style', 'text-decoration: line-through')" onmouseout="this.setAttribute('style', 'text-decoration: none;')" class="bullet">{{bullet}}</li>
```

I know there would have to be an input text field to add a new one and a save button, but other than that I have no idea how to implement this, nor could I find much on it. Would I use a model for this? JS? Just views.py/html and css within the template?

Comment: As someone new to Django and SO, it would be helpful to comment why this may be a bad question rather than down vote it.

Comment: What if you used form `input` boxes inside some `<li>` tags and populated the boxes with placeholders that are what has last been saved?

Comment: And while I did not downvote, my guess is that someone did because it lacks at least a start of an attempt to code this on your own. I agree that downvoters should leave comments all the same.

Comment: That makes sense. Would I set the input boxes default to what I want to have? I could see that working well for adding a new bullet, but how about when they want to delete one?

Comment: In that case, maybe put a tiny button with an 'x' in it next to each list element that, when clicked, the list item is eliminated. Possibly best to use javascript for that part.

Comment: Ok, so you need to create an array that you can push() and pop() with, and when the user is happy, submits that array as a POST object to be collected by a view, then that view can update `bullet_list`. However, if you hard code `bullet_list` like this in your view rather than using a model and a method to delete object entries in a database you will always get the same `bullet_list` on a page refresh.

Comment: That's understandable! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to change:

```
bullet_list = {'Apple starts with A','Banana starts with B','Carrot starts with C'}
```

to:

```
bullet_list = ['Apple starts with A','Banana starts with B','Carrot starts with C']
```

The context is an object '`{}`' but you want your bullet_list to be an array/list '`[]`'

Comment: Thanks. When I was trying to replicate my coded example, I thought I had a dictionary so wrote {'apple':'Apple starts with A', 'banana':'Banana starts with B', 'carrot':'Carrot starts with C'}, but then I realized I had a list so I removed the keys but forgot to change the braces to what I had.

Comment: No, I am still trying to implement JS (as @Matt Cremeens suggested) to do what I would like as I am new to JS